# Properties Format on Geojson to MongoDB/Mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, geojson, mongoengine

I would like to find a solution on what `DataField` I should give to a geojson with a `properties` column. Currently a geojson format below would not have any issues since it it would only need the `StringField()` and `PointField()`.

A geojson format looks like this:

```
{
name : "Timmy's Taco Truck",
  loc : {
    type : "Point",
    coordinates : [ 37.7577 , -122.4376 ]
  }
}
```

However for a geojson with this format:

```
{
   "type" : "Feature",
   "id" : "ID80001",
   "geometry":{"type": "LineString", "coordinates":[[122.332,14.241],[125.332,13.532]]},
   "properties":{ "name":"Dummy Name", "color":"#000000" }
}
```

Using a ***model*** like the one below:

```
from mongoengine import *
from colorful.fields import RGBColorField

class Geometry(Document):
   type = StringField()
   id = StringField()
   geometry = LineStringField()
   name = StringField() color= RGBColorField() ***OR*** properties = ???
```

If I use `EmbeddedDocumentField` and create a separate properties field it would result to `"properties": [{"name": "Dummy Name","color": "#000000"}]`

not:

`"properties": {"name": "Dummy Name","color": "#000000"}`

How can I preserve the geojson format in the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [DictField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DictField) or [DynamicDocument](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.DynamicDocument).

```
from mongoengine import *

class Geometry(Document):
   type = StringField()
   id = StringField()
   geometry = LineStringField()
   properties = DictField()


g = Geometry()
# Assuming id is unique
g.properties['id'] = {"name": "Dummy Name","color": "#000000"}
g.save()

db.Geometry.findOne()
{
    "_id": <some_id>
    "properties": {
        "<some_id>": {
            {"name": "Dummy Name","color": "#000000"}
        }
}
```

or, just access it using `index 0` of `EmbeddedDocumentField`?

```
print(properties[0])
{"name": "Dummy Name","color": "#000000"}
```

Comment: Yeah I actually re-read the docs and saw the DictField. :)) I hope this works perfectly all throughout. Thanks!